# 16.04: Terminal doesn't open by clicking on icon, ctrl-alt-t, or gnome-terminal in xterm

Tags: command-line, 16.04, gnome, python, gnome-terminal

Hi I am a beginner in using Ubuntu (16.04) and I recently installed new libraries for python3 Tensorflow, pandas, and a couple others. However, I lost the ability to open terminal using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>, clicking icon in applications, or gnome-terminal in xterm. When I do run in xterm I see

```
import error: cannot import name '_gi' from 'gi' (/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/gi/__init__.py)
```

I can open terminal by right clicking and selecting open terminal. Is it possible to restore the ability to open it the other ways?